# Android xml file referencing string shows error? how to fix it

Tags: android, deprecated

I have registered in string resource but stil i'm getting error

Error 1:error: `Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'hint' with value '@string/dcommand').`

Error 2:`android:password is deprecated: Use inputType instead`

Error 3:`[I18N] Hardcoded string "Try Command", should use @string resource`

Error 4: `error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/invalid').`

How to handle this errors???
plz help... thanks in advance...

Comment: see my answer it will help you to resolve your problem

Comment: For your string resources which are not showing up, try cleaning your project. Project > Clean

Comment: Error 2 and 3 will be warning for you only

Answer (score 0):

So for **Error 1 and Error 4**  You have to create a string in the string.xml that will be at this location

```
YourProjectName\res\values\string.xml 

 <string name="dcommand">Your text</string>
<string name="invalid">Your text</string>
```

For **Error 2**

```
android:inputType="textPassword"
```

For **Error 3**

```
Don't hardcode your text set them in the string.xml as i have done dcommand
```

Comment: yeah i have created in tha path of com.askselva.simple/res/values/string.xml file. everything i entered  correctly.. still it shows error. how could i fix this??

Answer (score 0):

```
Error 1:error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'hint' with value '@string/dcommand').
```

It looks fine, just solve other bugs and then clean your project this will also gone away.

```
Error 2:android:password is deprecated: Use inputType instead
```

It is deprecated, use `android:inputType="textPassword"` instead.

```
Error 3:[I18N] Hardcoded string "Try Command", should use @string resource
```

Its not good practice to use hard code text, android recommended you that define your `string` inside `@String.xml`

```
Error 4: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/invalid').
```

Again is the same as 1st one, clean the project and then check.

Hope its works for you!